# Can I use an XLL add-in with SpreadsheetGear

Tags: xll, spreadsheetgear

I have a custom add-in that I need to use in SpreadsheetGear.  Can I directly reference the XLL file, or is there a way of making an interface or wrapper to access it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpreadsheetGear has no APIs to interface with XLL files.  There are APIs to create your own custom functions within SpreadsheetGear, so you could re-implement your custom functions using this API.  I couldn't say whether it's possible to write some sort of wrapper around your XLL using SpreadsheetGear's Custom Function API.

For more information on our Custom Function API, see the SpreadsheetGear.CustomFunction namespace in our documentation (http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.6.0/SpreadsheetGear~SpreadsheetGear.CustomFunctions_namespace.html)

There's also a sample in the SpreadsheetGear Explorer Solutions for C#/VB (found in the "SpreadsheetGear 2010" folder under the Start Menu...assuming you have SG installed on your machine) that demonstrates building a simple custom function (under *Calculations > Custom Functions*).

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'm investigating the structure of the XLL to see what our next steps are. I know that C# can use DllImport to work with DLLs, so there is hope.